# click to scrollTop some pixels using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to load specific location in same page. But the problem is, the header is fixed on position top, When I click the links, the header go behind of the header. So I am not able to show some contents. Please visit this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mnuWN/11/). You can understand what I am try to say. 
I dont like to add `padding` and `margin`.

Comment: you have to add 1 more container, there is nothing to do with jquery

Comment: some thing edited in jquery.

Comment: I would put another div or something above the actual content as an anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to change your `HTML`. There can be only one `id` per page.

In the given fiddle, you have a repeating `<div id="one">`

Now, to get the scroll working, you could do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var hash = $(this).attr("href");
        //console.log($(hash).position().top);
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(hash).position().top - 50 }, 200);

    });
});
```

Here `$(hash).position().top` gets the position of the `div` on the page and I subtract 50 from it (the height of the fixed div).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnuWN/21/)
​

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not working. can you check once again.

Comment: Hi, Could you refine the question? http://jsfiddle.net/mnuWN/16/ seems to be working

Comment: yeah you right, but you forget to add `html` in animation line.